# Let's spin the [wheel] for ideas on how to handle this tag!

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

On AU, there is a [wheel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wheel) tag, with no usage guidance. From looking at the 14 questions tagged with it, the tag seems to refer to

- The `wheel` group - [a group used on some *nix systems to give a user access to the `sudo` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_(computing)#Wheel_group). The group may also be called the `sudo` group
- Questions regarding [a scroll wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_wheel) (may also be referred to as a "mouse wheel")
- [Python wheels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547651/what-are-wheels-used-for-and-why-are-they-helpful-in-the-context-of-installing?noredirect=1)

What should we do with this tag?

Comment: I am taking the time and effort to help this change happen, it's up to you guys to approve those edits, and after all the edits are made it is up to the mods to delete the tag. + I have created the "python-wheel" tag so you can add information to it.

Comment: The mods could add the <tag> status-completed </tag>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update: given that everyone agrees here, and no-one has objected, the questions have been re-tagged using the plan below

---

I propose that

- Questions about mouse/scroll wheels are re-tagged to use the [mouse-wheel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mouse-wheel) tag
- For questions about installing Python packages using wheels, use [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation) + [python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python)
- Re-tag the two questions about the wheel group to use the [groups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/groups) tag instead

Comment: Sounds good. I’ll wait a couple days in case anyone objects and/or has a reason not to, but if nobody does within a few days, I’ll go ahead and do it

Comment: Honestly I don't see a reason to object this.

Comment: Why do we need a [tag:python-wheel] tag? Shouldn't just [tag:software-installation]+[tag:python] (or [tag:python3]) suffice?

Comment: @muru That would work as well. I think a dedicated tag would be better as it is a dedicated/specific format, not just installing Python software. We also have a [deb] tag as well, which is a somewhat similar case. SO also has a [python-wheel] tag. That said, I don't feel super strongly about it and I wouldn't be opposed to doing something else, like what you've described

Comment: Yes, but (a) creating debs and snaps for Ubuntu are relevant questions for us, but creating Python wheels would in general be something to be asked on [so] (as opposed to simply installing them, which would be covered by [tag:software-installation] and [tag:python]), and (b) tags that nobody follows and curates are how we end up in situations like this in the first place

Comment: I do agree @muru , but creating python wheels doesn't necessarily mean that the tag is not required (There are Ubuntu-specific wheels as well).

Comment: @RishonJR that doesn't necessarily mean the tag is required either - unless there are users who're following the tag, there is nothing particularly useful that the tag does that you can't do with a search. It's just noise. I notice that no one is piping up about following the tag.

Comment: But let's see after a few months @muru . If nothing happens then we will remove the tag(Most likely).

Comment: @muru I noticed that you are removing the python-wheel tag. I don’t mind that you’re removing it (it seemed reasonable to add it IMO, but I don’t feel strongly about it), but once you’re done, would you mind editing this Meta answer to reflex that said tag is gone?

Comment: @cocomac sure, I'll edit after the next Roomba run for deleted tags